# Merging partitions on new computer

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I have a new laptop with several partitions on it and was hoping to merge them; but having never done that, I wanted to ask before I screw something up.

The output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` is:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           111,8G            
├─sda1 ext4    95,9G /          
├─sda2            1K            
└─sda5 swap    15,9G [SWAP]     
sdb           931,5G            
├─sdb1 ext4   810,4G            
└─sdb2 ntfs   121,1G            
sr0            1024M
```

I can see that i have around 930G in one partition and im running out of space on my main partition.  My goal is to merge the two and get easy access to that second bit , but i want to verify that i won't disrupt or destroy anything on my main partition by merging the two and of course need to know the best method to do so safely .

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the question to describe the goal of your intended "merge". You may want something else than managing partitions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gparted software, it has a graphical interface and it is very easy to understand and perform the operations.

$ sudo apt-get install gparted

Obs: Partition changes can cause data loss, be careful with the operations performed.

Comment: You cannot use gparted on mounted partitions. Generally you need to run from live installer which already has gparted. But if booting from one drive can edit partitions on another drive if no partitions are mounted.